# Read a locked .db file from Photos App with R

Tags: sql, r, database

I want to analize my Photos App data using `R`. I know there is a `photos.db` file in my Library which, I'd guess, have all the metadata on my pictures. I tried opening the file but I am getting the `Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : database is locked`

```
# To open any db file, you simply:
library(RSQLite)
filename <- "~Pictures/MyLibrary.photoslibrary/database/photos.db"
sqlite.driver <- dbDriver("SQLite")
db <- dbConnect(sqlite.driver, dbname = filename)
dbListTables(db)
```

Any idea of how can I analyze Photos App data or to open this file as a read-only db?

Thanks! :)

Comment: See [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DatabaseIsLocked), specifically: *SQLITE_LOCKED means the source of contention is internal and comes from the same database connection that received the SQLITE_LOCKED error.* Please post a full R code as you may be doing other things. Otherwise exit the R session and try again or restart CPU.

Comment: Thanks for your super fast reply @Parfait Literally, that's all I am running sot here is no more code. If I reset and close everything, I get the same `database is locked` error. Any further idea? If you have a Mac and use the Photos App, you may try it!

Comment: Yes, restarted it from scratch and Photos App never opened! Still getting the same unfriendly error message @Parfait Is it possible that the file is locked by default and there is NO way to open it? 
I even tried opening the file with Navicat and it simply does not want to be opened!